# How to escape double quotes for PHP's imap_search

Tags: php, imap

Suppose I have an email with the subject line

```
this's is a "TEST" of "quote's"
```

What string should I give the [imap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) function in order to find this email? These all failed to produce the desired email:

```
SUBJECT "this's is a "TEST" of "quote's""
SUBJECT "this's is a \"TEST\" of \"quote's\""
SUBJECT "this's is a \\"TEST\\" of \\"quote's\\""
SUBJECT "this's is a ""TEST"" of ""quote's"""
```

What method of escaping is needed for me to be able to search for a string with "double quotes" in the search parameter

EDIT: Removed the ALL in front of the SUBJECT.  It is still not returning values for any of the escape methods.

Comment: you need to remove the word `ALL`

Comment: @cmorrissey ALL will become a noop, since it means `ALL` AND `SUBJECT ...`

Comment: I still removed the ALL in the case when a Search string is given.  None of the search strings will find my specific email.